# How can I run only a specific function in celery, not the whole files tasks.py?

Tags: python, celery

I have 2 files. The first one is called tasks.py and looks like this

```
from celery import Celery
import time
app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://localhost')
def init():
    for i in range(30):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)

init()

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

The second one is called run_task.py

```
from tasks import add
r = add.delay(4, 4)
```

THe problem is I want the init() function to run only once in a worker (when it is started). Now it runs everytime the run_task.py is executed. How can I do it?

Comment: Are you starting the celery task just as a python script? If you are starting by running it with python in terminal it will always initialize all imports. Maybe you need for task creation some running application eg. create API, terminal APP

Comment: Can you please give some more information?

Comment: Why do you call `init()` this way? As I read your first script it seems evident that everytime you'll import this script, `init()` will be called. You could define `init()` as a non-recurring task.

Comment: Seems legit. How can I do it?

Comment: if i use __name__ == 'main' condition then celery worker does not execute the init() function eeither